# On XAdES-T, what goes for the EncapsulatedTimeStamp element? The TSTInfo or the TimeStampToken?

Tags: xml-signature, timestamping

On XAdES what goes for the EncapsulatedTimeStamp element? The TSTInfo or the TimeStampToken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that is the Timestamp token according to https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101900_101999/101903/01.04.02_60/ts_101903v010402p.pdf.

> note that the term time-stamp token used thorought the present
>   document does NOT refer to the TSA's response to a requesting client,
>   but the token generated by the TSA, which is present within this
>   response. In the case of RFC 3161 [10] protocol, the time-stamp token
>   term is referring to the timeStampToken field within the TimeStampResp
>   element (the TSA's response returned to the requesting client).